# Populate react formik form with existing data

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

i am new to react, can anyone explain to me how can i manipulate or repopulate my existing form from backend data in react.
I am trying to edit and existing item in the inventory that i wanna change values for. i am using formik with react and formik grid. for data i am using AXIOS.
What i am trying to do is to get edit a specific entry from my database which has changed values. it's like trying to update values

```
<Formik
          validationSchema={schema}
          initialValues={{
            name: "",
            numberOfSets: "0",
            sortValue: "0",
            boxType: "",
            price: "",
            photo: "",
          }}
          onSubmit={({
            name,
            numberOfSets,
            sortValue,
            boxType,
            price,
            photo,
          }) => {
            boxService.addBox(
              name,
              numberOfSets,
              sortValue,
              boxType,
              price,
              photo
            );
            alert("Box added Successfully!"); // Box or Gift it's same thing
            window.location.reload(false);
          }}
        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            setFieldValue,
          }) => {
            return (
              <Form
                form={form}
                name="edit-gift"
                onFinish={handleSubmit}
                {...layout}
                labelAlign="left"
              >
// These are the fields i am trying to manipulate 
                <Form.Item name="name" label="Name">
                  <Input
                    name="name"
                    title="Product Name"
                    dataIndex="name"
                    key="productName"
                    value={values.name}
                    onChange={(e) => setFieldValue("name", e.target.value)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    placeholder="Please enter Box Name"
                  />

                  {errors?.name && touched?.name && (
                    <Text type="danger">{errors?.name}</Text>
                  )}
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name="numberOfSets" label="Number of Sets">
                  <Input
                    name="numberOfSets"
                    type="number"
                    value={values.numberOfSets}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      setFieldValue("numberOfSets", e.target.value)
                    }
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    placeholder="Please enter Number of Sets"
                  />

                  {errors?.numberOfSets && touched?.numberOfSets && (
                    <Text type="danger">{errors?.numberOfSets}</Text>
                  )}
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name="sortVlaue" label="Sort Value">
                  <Input
                    name="sortVlaue"
                    type="number"
                    value={values.sortValue}
                    onChange={(e) => setFieldValue("sortVlaue", e.target.value)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    placeholder="Please enter soring value"
                  />

                  {errors?.numberOfBoxes && touched?.numberOfBoxes && (
                    <Text type="danger">{errors?.numberOfBoxes}</Text>
                  )}
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name="boxType" label="Type">
                  <Select
                    value={values.boxType}
                    onChange={(value) => setFieldValue("boxType", value)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    placeholder="Please enter Box Type"
                  >
                    <Select.Option value="reward">Reward</Select.Option>
                    <Select.Option value="doublerandom">
                      Double Random
                    </Select.Option>
                  </Select>

                  {errors?.boxType && (
                    <Text type="danger">{errors?.boxType}</Text>
                  )}
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name="price" label="Price">
                  <Input
                    name="price"
                    title="Product Price"
                    dataIndex="price"
                    key="price"
                    value={values.price}
                    onChange={(e) => setFieldValue("price", e.target.value)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    placeholder="Please enter Box Price"
                  />

                  {errors?.price && touched?.price && (
                    <Text type="danger">{errors?.price}</Text>
                  )}
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name="photo" label="Product Picture">
                  <div className="dropzone-container">
                    {values.photo && <img src={values.photo} alt=""></img>}

                    {!values.photo && (
                      <Dropzone
                        onDrop={(acceptedFiles) => {
                          acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
                            console.log(file);
                          });
                          let fr = new FileReader();
                          fr.onload = function () {
                            setFieldValue("photo", fr.result);
                            setFieldValue("imgName", acceptedFiles[0].name);
                            console.log(acceptedFiles[0]);
                          };

                          fr.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
                        }}
                        accept={{ "image/*": [] }}
                        maxSize={1000000}
                      >
                        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                          <section>
                            <div {...getRootProps({ style })}>
                              <input {...getInputProps()} />
                              <p>
                                Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to
                                select files
                              </p>
                              <aside>
                                Tips: The size ratio of the photo is: 750:216,
                                the maximum recommended size is 1M, and the
                                format is: .jpg, .jpeg, .png
                              </aside>
                            </div>
                          </section>
                        )}
                      </Dropzone>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item>
                  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                    Cofirm save
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to post where i am fetching data from and it could be that i am doing this wrong totally
const getBoxes = () => {
  return http
    .get("/box/getAllBox")
    .then((result) =>
      result.data.content.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, key: index }))
    );
};

Comment: Do you mean populating on initial load? If so, fetch data with axios from the endpoint that has the desired data and use them in `initialValues` like `name: results.data.name`.

Comment: ok, so i can fetch simply using Axios?

Comment: Yes. I think you can fetch on initial load using 
axios in useEffect or any data fetching library and use the data in the form values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

- rerender the `Formik` component when your data is available and pass it to the [`initialValues`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialvalues-values) prop by doing something like

```js
results?.data && <Formik initialValues={{...}}>...</Formik>
```

- or set the values manually with [`setValues`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields-reactsetstateaction-field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--void) after the data is available

```js
const {setValues, values, ...} = useFormik({...});
useEffect(() => {
   setValues(results?.data); // use any fields from your data
}, [results]} // this is the data from your api
```